# Regular expression java to extract the balance from a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a String which contains `" Dear user BAL= 1,234/ "`.
I want to extract `1,234` from the String using the regular expression. It can be `1,23`, `1,2345`, `5,213` or `500`

```
final Pattern p=Pattern.compile("((BAL)=*(\\s{1}\\w+))");
final Matcherm m = p.matcher(text);
if(m.find())
    return m.group(3);
else
 return "";
```

This returns `3`.
What regular expression should I make? I am new to regular expressions.

Comment: Why are you using so much parentheses? Seems like you try to get the string before the = and the numbers after and one time the whole string, is this what you want?

Comment: @BeowulfOF i only want the digits e.g. 1,233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You search in your regex for word characters `\w+` but you should search for digits with `\d+`.

Additionally there is the comma, so you need to match that as well.

I'd use

/.*BAL=\s([\d,]+(?=/).*/

as pattern and get only the number in the resulting group.

Explanation:
`.*` match anything before
`BAL=` match the string "BAL="
`\s` match a whitespace
`(`  start matching group
`[\d,]+` matches every digit or comma one ore more times
`(?=/)` match the former only if followed by a slash
`)` end matching group
`.*` matches anything thereaft

This is untestet, but it should work like this:

```
final Pattern p=Pattern.compile(".*BAL=\\s([\\d,]+(?=/)).*");
final Matcherm m = p.matcher(text);
if(m.find())
    return m.group(1);
else
 return "";
```

According to an [online tester](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html), the pattern above matches the text:

```
BAL= 1,234/
```

Comment: Patter.compile("/.([\d,]+)./") is this is what r u saying. this shows an error .

Comment: Yes, the slashes before and after don't go into your string representation of the regex. Normally regex literals are put between slashes to indicate its a pattern.

Comment: it says invalid escape sequence.

Comment: Right, its java and the backslash has to be escaped in a string. My fault.

Comment: As of your comment to the other question, I expanded my regex with positive lookahead and string literal before.

Comment: there is not need for a positive lookahead , just `BAL=*\\s([\\d,]+)` would be fine. And get the string you want from group index 1.

Comment: @avinash no, your pattern is short, but does not sanitize the input.

Answer (score 0):

If it didn't have to be extracted by the regular expression you could simply do:

```
// split on any whitespace into a 4-element array
String[] foo = text.split("\\s+");  
return foo[3];
```

Comment: actually there can be more such numbers in the text but i need to extract the one who starts with "BAL= " and ends with "/"